# How can I fix Ghost (glibc) BUG on Debian 6

Tags: debian, glibc

Problem is, that there seems to be no updates for glibc if I run

```
apt-get upgrade
```

How can I check if my system has this vulnerability, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following lines to /etc/apt/sources.list (see https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using):

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
```

Run

```
> apt-get update
```

Check that package list has been updated:

```
> apt-cache show libc6 | grep Version
Version: 2.11.3-4
Version: 2.11.3-4+deb6u4  # 'deb6u4' is the fixed version
```

Update libc

```
> apt-get install libc6
```

Check update result:

```
> dpkg -l libc6
```

... 'deb6u4' must be displayed in the list.

It is recommended to restart the system after fix.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Debian Security tracker](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2015-0235) page for this issue: it states that the Debian 6 glibc is affected, but that a fix is available in Debian 6 LTS.

To check your version of glibc:

```
dpkg -l libc6
```

The fixed version is 2.11.3-4+deb6u4, anything older than that is vulnerable.

You can find information on Debian LTS on [the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS), including how to install updates from it.