# GHOST vulnerability fix for Debian 6 Squeeze

Tags: linux, security, debian

I've been trying to update eglibc to fix a Debian 6 Squeeze system that is vulnerable to the GHOST exploit, but I haven't been able to so far.

I've gone through the relevant instructions [here](http://www.astiostech.com/blog/?p=161) but my system still remains vulnerable. (I am checking vulnerability by running the script located [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/cve-2015-0235-patch-ghost-on-debian-ubuntu-fedora-centos-rhel-linux/)). My libc version after update is 2.11.3-4.

I notice that on [Debian's Security Tracker](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/source-package/eglibc) that there is a fixed version of eglibc for eglibc on squeeze (lts), but not squeeze. I am running squeeze.

**How can I fix my version of squeeze? Do I need to upgrade to squeeze (lts)? If so, is that a painful and involved process or a simple and easy process?**

Much appreciated - thanks.

Comment: I've seen that question, but I don't think this is a duplicate since the suggested solution on that thread only works for Debian Squeeze LTS. Thanks for linking to that wiki in your response down below. I'm noticing that LTS only supports i386 and amd64, which appears to be the source of my problem.

Comment: Ah right, if you’re not running i386 or amd64 you’ll have to upgrade to Wheezy, or manually upgrade glibc and anything else that needs upgrading with it. I’ll delete my duplicate flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217363/how-can-i-fix-ghost-glibc-bug-on-debian-6). You really do need to upgrade to Squeeze LTS, but it’s simple enough if you’re running `i386` or `amd64`; the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS) has all the info.

Answer (score 0):

Get eglibc's source and compile to a .deb yourself.